# How would i get ubuntu on a pc I'm building?

Tags: system-installation

I want to build a pc for gaming using parts, but I don't like windows 10 and I don't want to pay 100 dollars for it. How would i get ubuntu on it?

Comment: Get the parts, assemble it and install yourself? O.o

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple actually. Here's how I go about it.

1 - Download the .iso of version you want to install. (making sure its compatible with your equipment, arm vs 32 vs 64 bit)

2 - Burn the ISO to disc (various tools exist to do this easily, can burn to USB too)

3 - Boot the PC, on which the OS will be installed, to the disc you just burned.

4 - Select Install. (I recommend making sure your new PC is plugged into internet) Following the prompts you can set it as you prefer. Drive space, keyboard layout, location, etc...

5 - Setup your Login credentials. Let the install finish.

Once its done, it should reboot your PC after ejecting your burned Disc. At which point the OS should be successfully installed, and the PC should now boot to the Ubuntu flavor you installed.

Enjoy.

Heres the link for the official walkthrough
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 0):

Use Nvidia cards and intel processors, AMD is cheaper and good quality but it might not work as expected in the latest Ubuntu which is Ubuntu 16.04LTS(Long Term Support)because 16.04LTS will support open source drivers only which will let AMD stuck at OpenGL 4.1.

wait till Ubuntu 16.04LTS gets fully released and get Nvidia cards and intel processors.

remember Linux is just starting in the gaming section and you might not find alot of AAA titles to play on Ubuntu while there are many ports that dont work like expected (batman was a disaster in windows and Linux).